# Postbuild plugin not running. "Build is worse than unstable"

Tags: ant, jenkins, post-build

I've set up some post build steps to update my github repository with the status of the build. However I'm getting some unfortunate errors from the post build plugin.

It says:

```
Match found for :FAILURES! : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Skipping post build task 0 - job status is worse than unstable : FAILURE
```

I suspect it's got something to do with the return code of my ant step, but not really sure where to go from here. Here's I'm including the ant definition and then the bottom of the log.

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit" depends="prepare">
  <exec executable="sh/runtest.sh" failonerror="true">
    <arg value='-d screenshot_url=http://184.169.148.19:8080/job/ASN Events/ws/build/screenshots/' />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Bottom of log:

```
 [exec] 
 [exec] FAILURES!
 [exec] Tests: 2072, Assertions: 6850, Errors: 2, Incomplete: 4, Skipped: 3.
 [exec] 5213
 [exec] I, [2013-06-18T04:55:14.851141 #5213]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5231 exit 0> worker=0
 [exec] I, [2013-06-18T04:55:14.851499 #5213]  INFO -- : master complete

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ASN Events/workspace/build.xml:154: exec returned: 2

Total time: 37 minutes 48 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Performing Post build task...
Match found for :FAILURES! : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Skipping post build task 0 - job status is worse than unstable : FAILURE
```